# Flutter dependencies problems

Tags: flutter

I am stuck with dependencies error and i can't figure how i can solve it.

Here are my plugins

```
version: 2.0.0+37

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^1.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.3
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.0
  firebase_auth_web: ^1.0.0
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^4.0.5955
  google_fonts: ^2.0.0
  table_calendar: ^2.3.3
  flutter_calendar_week:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/mduccc/flutter_calendar_week
      ref: 0.4.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.0
  flutter_reaction_button: ^1.0.7+3
  nanoid: ^1.0.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.0.0
  awesome_dialog: ^1.3.2
  flutter_animated_dialog: ^1.2.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.4
  flutter_colorpicker: ^0.3.4
  expandable: ^4.1.4
  firebase_analytics: ^7.1.0
  firebase_analytics_web: ^0.2.0
  http_parser: ^4.0.0
  google_mobile_ads: ^0.11.0+2
  purchases_flutter: ^3.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.2
  firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0
  flushbar: ^1.10.4
  i18n_extension: ^4.0.0
  syncfusion_flutter_core: ^18.4.46
  syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^18.4.46
  syncfusion_flutter_datepicker: ^18.4.46-beta
  syncfusion_localizations: ^18.4.46
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
```

And here is my error since i have firebase: ^9.0.0

```
Running "flutter pub get" in projetge...                        
Because every version of firebase_analytics_web depends on firebase ^7.3.0 which depends on http_parser ^3.0.0, every version of firebase_analytics_web requires http_parser ^3.0.0.

So, because projetge depends on both firebase_analytics_web ^0.2.0 and http_parser ^4.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because projetge depends on both firebase_analytics_web ^0.2.0 and http_parser ^4.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

So if i understand well i need to go lower on firebase plugins but if i do so i will get other plugins dependencies errors so i am totally stuck. Do i have to wait for firebase_analytics_web to get updated? It doesn't make sense, maybe we can skip dependencies or get 2 versions of one plugins ?

Comment: just remove all version number from `pubspec.yaml` of all conflicting dependecies

Comment: So you mean i erase only the number and not the line? What will be done then ? Do i still get the addon

Comment: yes pub will get all compatable dependecies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dependency_overrides after your dependencies

```
dependency_overrides
  http_parser: ^4.0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using 'flutter pub outdated' command, you can find solution of dependencies.
If that command suggest that there is proper solution,
you need to package's update.

[image]

Comment: And if they are no suggestions? What should i do

Answer (score 1):

use `http_parser ^3.0.0` instead of `http_parser ^4.0.0`. Because you are using `firebase_analytics_web: ^0.2.0` and this is the latest version of it that's why you need to change the version of `http_parser`.

Comment: If i use 3.0.0 i get other error for firebasecore dependencies. If i lower all firebase core i need to go down on intl too and the latest version of flutter i need intl 0.17 that’s why i am stuck

Comment: can you please mention the error for using http_parser ^3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The error is solved using the commande :
flutter pub upgrade

The tool found the perfect combinaison i needed. Thanks flutter